# Choose return type based calling structure

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm sure this is an easy question for experienced programmers, but I've never had to do this before - Suppose I have a custom object looking as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{       
    public Dictionary<string,string> ToDictString()
    {
        Dictionary<string,string>  retval = new Dictionary<string,string>;
        // Whatever code
        return retval;
    }

    public Dictionary<string,int> ToDictInt()
    {
        Dictionary<string,int>  retval = new Dictionary<string,int>;
        // Whatever code
        return retval;
    }

}
```

So, in my code, I can write something as follows:

```
MyClass FakeClass = new MyClass();
Dictionary<string,int> MyDict1 = FakeClass.ToDictInt();
Dictionary<string,string> MyDict2 = FakeClass.ToDictString();
```

And that works fine, but what I would like to be able to do is have a single method in `MyClass` called, say `ToDict()` that **could return either type of dictionary depending on the return type expected**

So, for example, I would have:

```
MyClass FakeClass = new MyClass();

// This would be the same as calling ToDictInt due to the return type:
Dictionary<string,int> MyDict1 = FakeClass.ToDict();

// This would be the same as calling ToDictString due to the return type:
Dictionary<string,string> MyDict2 = FakeClass.ToDict();
```

So, one method name, but it knows what to return based upon the variable that is to be returned... How would I write the method in my class to do I do that?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: It's not possible the way You described it, but You may define a generic method and use it with appropriate type on each call, so the signature would be: `Dictionary<string, T> ToDict<T>()`. This is a little bit different than what You asked for, but it may be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.  The overload resolution algorithm does not take the context of the method invocation expression into consideration, and so it would result in an ambiguity error in the example that you've mentioned.

You'll need to have two different method names (or a difference in the parameter list) for the methods to have a different return type.

Comment: To further this point, suppose you were to call the method without assigning the value to a variable.

Comment: Even in C++, which tends to be more forgiving than C#, overloads cannot only differ by return type.

Comment: Thanks so much as always, @servy! - I was afraid that was the case... I was wondering about it due to things such as code that looks like this: `DataRow dr = new DataRow();`  ;   `string myfield = dr.Field<string>("FieldName");` where you can cast what you're getting back from the `Field()` method...

Comment: @JohnBustos That is not limiting the possible return types to just two possibilities.  It is writing a *single* overload that supports *every single possible type* as a return type.  It also doesn't consider context at all.  The expression `dr.Field<string>("FieldName");` has a type, and that type is `string`.  No context is needed to determine its type, in contrast to, say, lambdas, which actually do require their context to determine a type.

Comment: @JohnBustos - Given that you're looking for something like the DataRow's functionality, I think Eric J's solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics to achieve something close to what you want

```
public Dictionary<string,T> ToDict<T>()
{
    Dictionary<string,T>  retval = new Dictionary<string,T>();
    // Whatever code
    return retval;
}
```

You would need to specify the type parameter when using it

```
var result = myClass.ToDict<int>();
```

This moves the return type qualifier from the method name to a type parameter, and is the closest you can get due to the issues mentioned by @Servy.

Comment: The issue here is that you aren't restricting the dictionary to just two possible return types; any possible type can be supplied.  If you check it at runtime, then you've lost your static typing.  This should really only be done if any possible type really is a valid valid, in which case using overloads *isn't* a valid alternative.

Comment: @Servy: True, though with both `string` and `int` in the provided example, there is no `where` restriction that covers types the OP needs to support.  Just mentioning an option that may or may not be useful to the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, Eric! - I was also thinking of something like that or even using an enumeration from my class to define return type... I was just hoping I wouldn't even need to go that far... Thank you for a great idea, though!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos This solution creates way more problems than it solves here, assuming only `int` and `string` are valid (or any other possible finite set of return types).  It will be easier on the caller and the implementation to just have different overloads, and it also maintains static type safety, unlike this solution.

Comment: @Servy: `assuming only int and string are valid`... I agree with you, if that constraint is valid.  The OP may or may not actually want to support a wide range of types.  If he's looking at something like `Field<T>` as implied in one of his comments, your assumption might not be valid.

Comment: Eric, Thank you SO MUCH for your solution, it is what I was asking for and you answered it perfectly, but it did definitely raise the fear of unknown errors showing up at runtime since truly, only `int` and `string` are valid... Just sucks for this specific situation, unfortunately. THANK YOU!!